# phpunit cannot find app classes in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, phpunit, pear, yii2

Trying to set up phpunit with the Yii2 framework.  I am using Composer for managing dependencies

```
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
},
```

I used Pear to install PHPUnit, following the instructions in the [manual](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.pdf).  My OS is ubuntu 12.04.
I am working with the basic app file structure:

```
-app 
   -tests
      -unit
         -models
            -UserTest.php
   -models
      -User.php
```

I run the UserTest from within /tests/unit/models, and I get a PHP fatal error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'User' not found
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/local/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/local/bin/phpunit:615
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run()     
phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:129
PHP   4. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest()    
phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:150
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->loadSuiteClass() 
phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:104
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Runner_StandardTestSuiteLoader->load() 
phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:168
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::checkAndLoad() 
phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php:77
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load() 
phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Util/Fileloader.php:76
PHP   9. include_once() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Util/Fileloader.php:92
PHP  10. require_once() /home/thomas/Documents/records/tests/unit/models/UserTest.php:4
```

My test looks like this.  Notice that I've tried including the class directly to no avail.

```
<?php

//set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . getcwd/../../../);
//require_once('models/User.php');
//require_once('db/ActiveRecord.php');

class UserTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

public function testForAttributeId() {
    $this-> assertClassHasAttribute('id', 'User');
}
public function testFindIdentity() {
    $userobj = new \app\models\User();
    $user = $userobj->findIdentity(hash('sha256', 871821997));
    $this-> assertContainsOnlyInstancesOf('User', $user);
    $this-> assertEquals($user->id, 871821997);
    $this-> assertEquals($user->name, 'Thomas Dressler');
}

/*  
 public function testEmpty()
 {
     $stack = array();
     $this->assertEmpty($stack);
     return $stack;
 }
 /**
 * @depends testEmpty
 *
 public function testPush(array $stack)
 {
     array_push($stack, 'foo');
     $this->assertEquals('foo', $stack[count($stack)-1]);
     $this->assertNotEmpty($stack);
     return $stack;
 }
 /**
 * @depends testPush
 *
 public function testPop(array $stack)
 {
     $this->assertEquals('foo', array_pop($stack));
     $this->assertEmpty($stack);
 }*/
}
?>
```

I've tried upgrading Pear, re-installing PHPUnit, and checking the paths in php.ini.  My path looks like

```
include_path = ".:/usr/share/php:~/.composer/vendor/bin/:/usr/share/php/PHPunit:/usr/share/php/PEAR"
```

Comment: Did you try to run tests using Codeception?

Comment: I also have problems with codeception.  My codecept.phar file is in my web root.  When I go into my app directory (below web root) and run `php /../codecept.phar build` I get an error that "the input file could not be found."   My composer.phar file is in my web root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install codeceptor using composer (in yii2 app root run `php composer.phar require "codeception/codeception:*"`)
2. In the app root run `vendor/bin/codecept build`

Comment: Thanks Alexey!  It turned out that I wasn't paying close enough attention to the error messages when trying to intall codeception.  I had recently updated php, and I guess my CURL extension was missing, so many of the dependencies weren't being installed.  Your answer helped me solve it right away.  Just a side not- I specifically installed codeception: 1.8.3, which immediately started working more smoothly for me with the current Yii2